# Calculated column in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, calculated-columns

I am having this table and I want to make the calculated column form the far right.

[image: Sample Table]

My logic is the following:

```
For all IDs 
   For all rows 
     IF (delta <= 2 OR delta = NULL) { "Observation " + counter' }
     ELSE { counter +1; "Observation " + counter; }
   reset counter to 1
```

But I can translate it in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when delta > 2 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by time end) + 1
from t;
```

This produces a number.  You can construct the string however you like.